# Permissions set for documents in a library don't work from hyperlinks

Tags: permissions

I have a Sharepoint site which contains a document library with several folders, a forum etc. I have set up a group (30 people) who can view the site.

One of the folders contains about 40 Word Documents which were created in either Microsoft Office 2010 or Mac 2011.  Each of these document has unique permissions-with different editors from the group being able to edit   individual documents.  When I view the documents in the library there don't seem to be a problem. Members can only see the documents in this folder that they have a right to edit.

Buuut. On the front page of the site I have a table set up with hyperlinks to these documents and all the permissions seem to disappear when I access the documents through the hyperlink. Any member of the group can go in there and edit any of the documents.

Any idea of the problem.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: After they edit the document, do the document properties show the person you expect to be listed as the last editor? I suspect that you are not in the user context that you think you are. I wonder what the behavior is when accessed through Explorer view? Did you break inheritance on those files?

Comment: Hi I think that you are right. It seems the issue has been that even when we are logged in as another user from our own PC’s Sharepoint still sees us as site owners meaning we have access to all the documents etc.  

We have asked one of the editors with restricted access to log in and things seemed fine and they can only see the documents that they have access to. Thanks so much for the help.Tara